# How to perform AWS S3 Multipart Copy with golang

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I was looking at the AWS golang documentation for [S3 Copy Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.CopyObject) function, it contains the following details for handling large file uploads

> However, to copy an object greater >than 5 GB, you must use the multipart upload Upload Part - >Copy API. For more information, see Copy Object Using the REST Multipart Upload API >(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjctsUsingRESTMPUapi.html).

When I follow that link, it only contains code examples for Java and .Net
[image: Only Java and .Net examples]

Am I missing some documentation/example somewhere showing how to copy an existing large file in S3 using the golang client?

Comment: AWS usually points you to the main documentation where the examples are in just a couple of languages. That doesn't mean that it can't be done with another language SDK. They can. At the end of the day, each SDK is just a wrapper around their REST API. Have you looked at the following Golang SDK docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.CreateMultipartUpload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it took some experimenting but I finally got the multipart copy working

```
//imports
import (
  "context"
  "strconv"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
  log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

//constant for number of bits in 5 megabyte chunk
const max_part_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024

//helper function to build the string for the range of bits to copy
func buildCopySourceRange(start int64, objectSize int64) string {
    end := start + max_part_size - 1
    if end > objectSize {
        end = objectSize - 1
    }
    startRange := strconv.FormatInt(start, 10)
    stopRange := strconv.FormatInt(end, 10)
    return "bytes=" + startRange + "-" + stopRange
}

//function that starts, perform each part upload, and completes the copy
func MultiPartCopy(sess *session.Session, sourceBucket string, sourceKey string, destBucket string, destKey string) error {
    svc := s3.New(sess)

    ctx, cancelFn := context.WithTimeout(context.TODO(), 10*time.Minute)
    defer cancelFn()

    //struct for starting a multipart upload
    startInput := s3.CreateMultipartUploadInput{
        Bucket: &destBucket,
        Key:    &destKey,
    }

    //send command to start copy and get the upload id as it is needed later
    var uploadId string
    createOutput, err := svc.CreateMultipartUploadWithContext(ctx, &startInput)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if createOutput != nil {
        if createOutput.UploadId != nil {
            uploadId = *createOutput.UploadId
        }
    }
    if uploadId == "" {
        return errors.New("No upload id found in start upload request")
    }

    var i int64
    var partNumber int64 = 1
    copySource := "/" + sourceBucket + "/" + sourceKey
    parts := make([]*s3.CompletedPart, 0)
    numUploads := fileSize / max_part_size
    log.Infof("Will attempt upload in %d number of parts to %s", numUploads, destKey)
    for i = 0; i < fileSize; i += max_part_size {
        copyRange := buildCopySourceRange(i, fileSize)
        partInput := s3.UploadPartCopyInput{
            Bucket:          &destBucket,
            CopySource:      &copySource,
            CopySourceRange: &copyRange,
            Key:             &destKey,
            PartNumber:      &partNumber,
            UploadId:        &uploadId,
        }
        log.Debugf("Attempting to upload part %d range: %s", partNumber, copyRange)
        partResp, err := svc.UploadPartCopy(&partInput)

        if err != nil {
            log.Error("Attempting to abort upload")
            abortIn := s3.AbortMultipartUploadInput{
                UploadId: &uploadId,
            }
            //ignoring any errors with aborting the copy
            svc.AbortMultipartUploadRequest(&abortIn)
            return fmt.Errorf("Error uploading part %d : %w", partNumber, err)
        }

        //copy etag and part number from response as it is needed for completion
        if partResp != nil {
            partNum := partNumber
            etag := strings.Trim(*partResp.CopyPartResult.ETag, "\"")
            cPart := s3.CompletedPart{
                ETag:       &etag,
                PartNumber: &partNum,
            }
            parts = append(parts, &cPart)
            log.Debugf("Successfully upload part %d of %s", partNumber, uploadId)
        }
        partNumber++
        if partNumber%50 == 0 {
            log.Infof("Completed part %d of %d to %s", partNumber, numUploads, destKey)
        }
    }

    //create struct for completing the upload
    mpu := s3.CompletedMultipartUpload{
        Parts: parts,
    }

    //complete actual upload
    //does not actually copy if the complete command is not received
    complete := s3.CompleteMultipartUploadInput{
        Bucket:          &destBucket,
        Key:             &destKey,
        UploadId:        &uploadId,
        MultipartUpload: &mpu,
    }
    compOutput, err := svc.CompleteMultipartUpload(&complete)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error completing upload: %w", err)
    }
    if compOutput != nil {
        log.Infof("Successfully copied Bucket: %s Key: %s to Bucket: %s Key: %s", sourceBucket, sourceKey, destBucket, destKey)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Where did `fileSize` variable come from?

Answer (score 6):

The same approach as [@Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67539597/14048071) but using **AWS-SDK-GO-V2**:

```
import (
    "logger"
    "context"
    "errors"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3/types"
)

//constant for number of bits in 5 megabyte chunk
const max_part_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024

var log *logger.Logger

//helper function to build the string for the range of bits to copy
func buildCopySourceRange(start int64, objectSize int64) string {
    end := start + max_part_size - 1
    if end > objectSize {
        end = objectSize - 1
    }
    startRange := strconv.FormatInt(start, 10)
    stopRange := strconv.FormatInt(end, 10)
    return "bytes=" + startRange + "-" + stopRange
}

//function that starts, perform each part upload, and completes the copy
func MultiPartCopy(svc *s3.Client, fileSize int64, sourceBucket string, sourceKey string, destBucket string, destKey string) error {
    log = logger.GetLogger()

    ctx, cancelFn := context.WithTimeout(context.TODO(), 10*time.Minute)
    defer cancelFn()

    //struct for starting a multipart upload
    startInput := s3.CreateMultipartUploadInput{
        Bucket: &destBucket,
        Key:    &destKey,
    }

    //send command to start copy and get the upload id as it is needed later
    var uploadId string
    createOutput, err := svc.CreateMultipartUpload(ctx, &startInput)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if createOutput != nil {
        if createOutput.UploadId != nil {
            uploadId = *createOutput.UploadId
        }
    }
    if uploadId == "" {
        return errors.New("No upload id found in start upload request")
    }

    var i int64
    var partNumber int32 = 1
    copySource := "/" + sourceBucket + "/" + sourceKey
    parts := make([]types.CompletedPart, 0)
    numUploads := fileSize / max_part_size
    log.Infof("Will attempt upload in %d number of parts to %s", numUploads, destKey)
    for i = 0; i < fileSize; i += max_part_size {
        copyRange := buildCopySourceRange(i, fileSize)
        partInput := s3.UploadPartCopyInput{
            Bucket:          &destBucket,
            CopySource:      &copySource,
            CopySourceRange: &copyRange,
            Key:             &destKey,
            PartNumber:      partNumber,
            UploadId:        &uploadId,
        }
        log.Debugf("Attempting to upload part %d range: %s", partNumber, copyRange)
        partResp, err := svc.UploadPartCopy(context.TODO(), &partInput)

        if err != nil {
            log.Error("Attempting to abort upload")
            abortIn := s3.AbortMultipartUploadInput{
                UploadId: &uploadId,
            }
            //ignoring any errors with aborting the copy
            svc.AbortMultipartUpload(context.TODO(), &abortIn)
            return fmt.Errorf("Error uploading part %d : %w", partNumber, err)
        }

        //copy etag and part number from response as it is needed for completion
        if partResp != nil {
            partNum := partNumber
            etag := strings.Trim(*partResp.CopyPartResult.ETag, "\"")
            cPart := types.CompletedPart{
                ETag:       &etag,
                PartNumber: partNum,
            }
            parts = append(parts, cPart)
            log.Debugf("Successfully upload part %d of %s", partNumber, uploadId)
        }
        partNumber++
        if partNumber%50 == 0 {
            log.Infof("Completed part %d of %d to %s", partNumber, numUploads, destKey)
        }
    }

    //create struct for completing the upload
    mpu := types.CompletedMultipartUpload{
        Parts: parts,
    }

    //complete actual upload
    //does not actually copy if the complete command is not received
    complete := s3.CompleteMultipartUploadInput{
        Bucket:          &destBucket,
        Key:             &destKey,
        UploadId:        &uploadId,
        MultipartUpload: &mpu,
    }
    compOutput, err := svc.CompleteMultipartUpload(context.TODO(), &complete)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error completing upload: %w", err)
    }
    if compOutput != nil {
        log.Infof("Successfully copied Bucket: %s Key: %s to Bucket: %s Key: %s", sourceBucket, sourceKey, destBucket, destKey)
    }
    return nil
}
```

[@Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117376/mike) one question. You used `AbortMultipartUploadRequest` which is not present in **AWS-SDK-GO-V2** so I used the `AbortMultipartUpload` instead, hope it doesn't cause much difference?

Comment: Where did `fileSize` variable come from?

Comment: You will likely want to call the ListObjectsV2 to look up if the objects exists before copying and get result of the call should contain the files and their size https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3#Client.ListObjectsV2

Comment: Excellent answer. I would like to emphasize that the ETag appears to be required when building `CompletedPart`. I was getting a vague "api error MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema" error until I found this answer and added the etag.

Answer (score 1):

The two other solutions are quite slow. Using goroutines can speed this up significantly, since most of the wait time is on the AWS side.

Here's a copy of the V1 solution Mike provided, but using goroutines (and properly getting the fileSize, which seems to be something he left out).

```
// constant for number of bits in 5 megabyte chunk
const max_part_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024

// helper function to build the string for the range of bits to copy
func buildCopySourceRange(start int64, objectSize int64) string {
    end := start + max_part_size - 1
    if end > objectSize {
        end = objectSize - 1
    }
    startRange := strconv.FormatInt(start, 10)
    stopRange := strconv.FormatInt(end, 10)
    return "bytes=" + startRange + "-" + stopRange
}

// function that starts, perform each part upload, and completes the copy
func MultiPartCopy(sess *session.Session, sourceBucket string, sourceKey string, destBucket string, destKey string) error {
    svc := s3.New(sess, aws.NewConfig().WithRegion(S3_REGION))

    ctx, cancelFn := context.WithTimeout(context.TODO(), 10*time.Minute)
    defer cancelFn()

    headInput := s3.HeadObjectInput{
        Bucket:    aws.String(sourceBucket),
        Key:       aws.String(sourceKey),
    }

    result, err := svc.HeadObject(&headInput)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fileSize := *result.ContentLength

    //send command to start copy and get the upload id as it is needed later
    var uploadId string
    startInput := s3.CreateMultipartUploadInput{
        Bucket: &destBucket,
        Key:    &destKey,
    }
    createOutput, err := svc.CreateMultipartUploadWithContext(ctx, &startInput)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if createOutput != nil {
        if createOutput.UploadId != nil {
            uploadId = *createOutput.UploadId
        }
    }
    if uploadId == "" {
        return errors.New("No upload id found in start upload request")
    }

    var i int64
    var partNumberCounter int64 = 1
    copySource := "/" + sourceBucket + "/" + sourceKey
    numUploads := (fileSize + max_part_size - 1) / max_part_size
    fmt.Println("Will attempt upload in ", numUploads, " number of parts to ", destKey)

    type Result struct {
        Error      error
        Part       *s3.CompletedPart
        PartNumber int64
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan Result, numUploads)

    count := 0
    for i = 0; i < fileSize; i += max_part_size {
        wg.Add(1)
        count += 1
        go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, partStart int64, partNumber int64) {
            defer wg.Done()
            var err error
            var part *s3.CompletedPart
            copyRange := buildCopySourceRange(partStart, fileSize)
            partInput := s3.UploadPartCopyInput{
                Bucket:          &destBucket,
                CopySource:      &copySource,
                CopySourceRange: &copyRange,
                Key:             &destKey,
                PartNumber:      &partNumber,
                UploadId:        &uploadId,
            }
            fmt.Println("Attempting to upload part", partNumber, "range:", copyRange)
            partResp, err := svc.UploadPartCopy(&partInput)

            if err != nil {
                err = fmt.Errorf("Error uploading part %d : %w", partNumber, err)
            } else if partResp != nil {
                //copy etag and part number from response as it is needed for completion
                partNum := partNumber
                etag := strings.Trim(*partResp.CopyPartResult.ETag, "\"")
                cPart := s3.CompletedPart{
                    ETag:       &etag,
                    PartNumber: &partNum,
                }
                fmt.Println("Successfully uploaded part", partNumber, "of", uploadId)
                part = &cPart
            }
            ch <- Result{Error: err, Part: part, PartNumber: partNumber}
        }(&wg, i, partNumberCounter)
        partNumberCounter += 1
    }

    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)
    orderedParts := make([]*s3.CompletedPart, numUploads)
    for r := range ch {
        if r.Error != nil {
            fmt.Println("Attempting to abort upload")
            abortIn := s3.AbortMultipartUploadInput{
                UploadId: &uploadId,
            }
            //ignoring any errors with aborting the copy
            svc.AbortMultipartUploadRequest(&abortIn)
            return r.Error

        }
        if r.Part != nil {
            orderedParts[r.PartNumber-1] = r.Part
        }
    }

    // Filter out any nils from the parts list
    parts := make([]*s3.CompletedPart, 0)
    for _, part := range orderedParts {
        if part != nil {
            parts = append(parts, part)
        }

    }

    //create struct for completing the upload
    mpu := s3.CompletedMultipartUpload{
        Parts: parts,
    }

    //complete actual upload
    //does not actually copy if the complete command is not received
    complete := s3.CompleteMultipartUploadInput{
        Bucket:          &destBucket,
        Key:             &destKey,
        UploadId:        &uploadId,
        MultipartUpload: &mpu,
    }
    compOutput, err := svc.CompleteMultipartUpload(&complete)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error completing upload: %w", err)
    }
    if compOutput != nil {
        fmt.Println("Successfully copied Bucket:", sourceBucket, "Key:", sourceKey, "to Bucket:", destBucket, "Key:", destKey)
    }
    return nil
}
```